# Jsoup example to read data form different html's page (or) websites? should be reusable to any website

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I have a requirement to read data from different websites using `Jsoup` html parser   (Ex: name, city, state, zip etc.). I can able to read the data from one website. but the problem is my code should be reusable to other websites. but in the other website elements and their position is different to first website. How to achieve this. please suggest any pattern or any examples.   thanks.

Comment: http://jsoup.org/ has a nice doc

Comment: can u provide exact link please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll get this straight for you, there is NO WAY to achieve a general parser to scrape all websites. I've worked at a company where I had to scrape 30 websites. And I literally had to write one for every website.

You can however create general utility classes that **helps** you to process the data you've parsed.

Comment: yes i know, but any xml or json configuration way to config the elements for each website and read element data from there. because code will be reused??

Comment: Yes you could do that, inspect each website and map their element selectors in your xml file. Then when you scrape the websites you just parse the xml to get the corresponding element selector. However this still requires you to go through each website...if that's ok with you :)

Comment: thanks @Joel Min. i got it. i do configure the website url's and elements in Json file. i read from there. lot of code reduced. thanks.